# Python: using lmfit to fit a multi-variable equation

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares, data-fitting, lmfit

I have an expression that has two known/independent variables (x, c) and a dependent variable (y). All three have defined values, and I am trying to fit to some additional parameters.

I've managed to get the following code snippet to work, albeit I cannot seem to access the result (to compare to the original data). The fit works and a result is provided (at least, a preliminary one), but I cannot seem to evaluate the fit model to generate a result.

```
concVal = np.array([23.7268, 47.28539, 93.90479, 185.2011, 360.3914, 683.8195, 1240.417, 2091.683])
theta = np.array([0.911222, 0.869937, 0.83757, 0.792522, 0.731106, 0.654575, 0.576003, 0.455225])
lnCdOA2 = np.array([0.749078, 1.105725, 1.376938, 1.727125, 2.201455, 2.684985, 3.001148, 3.25525])
xData = np.arange(concVal[0], concVal[-1], 0.005)

def thetaLnFunction(x, c, a, b, k1, k2):
    return ((a*c) / (k1*x + c)) + ((b*c) / (k2*x + c))

model = Model(thetaLnFunction, independent_vars=['x', 'c'])
params = model.make_params(a=1, b=1, k1=1, k2=1)

fit = model.fit(theta, params, x = concVal, c = lnCdOA2)

fitEval = []
for x in xData:
    fitEval.append(fit[0].eval(x=x))

plt.plot(concVal, theta)
plt.plot(xData, fitEval)
plt.show()
```

After running this code, I get '`TypeError: 'ModelResult' object does not support indexing`', despite using this method in previous fits. Is there any way I can evaluate this model? If I change the evaluation to `fit.eval(x=x)` instead of `fit[0].eval(x=x)`, my plot returns many curves.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have `fit = model.fit(...)` and then `fit[0]`.

The error is that the ModelResult (`fit`) can't be indexed.
What do you expect `fit[0]` to mean?

If you want to evaluate the fit result at different `x` values, why not just do `fitEval = fit.eval(x=xData)`?